# how do I merge array of hashes summing by the value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
[{:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>10},
 {:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>10},
 {:id=>2, :book=>{:title=>"title2", :desc=>"title2", :author=>"title2"}, :pages=>30}]
```

How do I sum `pages` value leaving only unique keys? 
Eg.:

```
[{:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>20},
 {:id=>2, :book=>{:title=>"title2", :desc=>"title2", :author=>"title2"}, :pages=>30}]
```

Comment: This is a pure Ruby question, so I don't believe it should have a Rails tag. I would only have the single tag "ruby", but "hash" does no harm. Tags are used to facilitate searches (filtering in or out) so make sure your tags are neither misleading nor unhelpful. The Rails tag, for example, could cause readers who filter out Rails questions to miss your question, or waste time of those who are not interested in pure-Ruby questions.

Comment: Actually @CarySwoveland this looks very much like a Rails question, but it could be the wrong question.  If this data is from a database the OP should be using `DISTINCT ON` (Postgres) or `GROUP BY` (MySQL) and not pulling all the data out of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's group by id and map each result to a structure where the pages are the sum of all the pages for that id

```
array.
  group_by { |item| item[:id] }.
  map do |id, items| 
    page_sum = items.sum { |i| i[:pages] }
    Hash[:id, id, :book, items.first[:book], :pages, page_sum] 
  end
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for a nested hash with many keys, without needing to declare the hash keys?

Comment: open a question with an example. it's hard for me understand otherwise

Comment: I found a way to recursively sum a hash into a single hash with Hashie `deep_merge`: https://github.com/hashie/hashie/blob/v5.0.0/README.md#deepmerge

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  {:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>10},
  {:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>10},
  {:id=>2, :book=>{:title=>"title2", :desc=>"title2", :author=>"title2"}, :pages=>30}
]
```

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(pages: o[:pages] + n[:pages]) }
end.values
  #=> [{:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>30},
  #    {:id=>2, :book=>{:title=>"title2", :desc=>"title2", :author=>"title2"}, :pages=>30}]
```

Note the receiver of `values` equals

```
{1=>{:id=>1, :book=>{:title=>"title1", :desc=>"title1", :author=>"title1"}, :pages=>30},
 2=>{:id=>2, :book=>{:title=>"title2", :desc=>"title2", :author=>"title2"}, :pages=>30}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs the block

```
{ |_,o,n| o.merge(pages: o[:pages] + n[:pages]) }
```

to determine the values of keys (the block variable `_`) that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for an explanation of the block variables `o` and `n`.

`Hash#update` and [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) are the two methods one generally reaches for when dealing with problems of this kind. Either can be used. They are roughly equal in efficiency, so the choice is largely one of personal preference.